# How to change the language / locale in Dash (Plotly) or the label of the Plotly toolbar?

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly, plotly-dash

[Plotly Toolbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zy3H.png)

I have been able to successfully modify Plotly's toolbar in Dash using a dict (config) passed to dash_core_components.Graph

Now I want to change the "tooltip" or label of the remaining buttons to another language. 
The documentation states that I can change de locale (language) of the labels using the "locale" parameter. I've seen this both in JavaScript and R docs, being applied to Plotly Graphs or to dash_core_components.Graph:

https://plot.ly/r/locales/

Now I need to do this in Python, but I haven't been able to do this. This is what I've tried:

```
config_plots = {'modeBarButtonsToRemove':["sendDataToCloud","lasso2d","pan2d","autoScale2d","select2d","zoom2d","zoomIn2d", "zoomOut2d"],
            "locale":"de"}

dcc.Graph(id="plot",config=config_plots,
              figure={"data":plotdata,"layout":layout})
```

I have added the locale parameter as well to plotly graphs (plotly.graph_objs) and tried with different locales I know that exist, but I've had no luck so far.

The question:
How can I customize the text of the labels? Am I missing something using the locale parameter? **Is there any way to change the text of the labels so I can translate it without using the locale parameter**?

Please note that I know very little of JavaScript so I would prefer to do this in Python if possible

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [this plotly documentation](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/tree/master/dist#to-include-localization) you need to register any new language first.

In your case this means you need to add

```
https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-locale-de-latest.js
```

to your dashboard.

Either by

```
app.scripts.append_script({"external_url": "https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-locale-de-latest.js"})
```

or by downloading the js file and coping it to the assets folder in your dashboards root folder.

See https://dash.plot.ly/external-resources for more information.

Comment: Phifre, thanks. It worked! I could change the Plotly toolbar language, but it hasn't impacted the Dash Core Components. For example, I have a Date picker Range that I would like to translate as well. I tried several ways to select the locale in the dcc but couldn't solve it. Do you know how to apply locale to dash core components?

Answer (score 1):

In `django-dash-plotly` I had to do this:

- Add the localization script to the external scripts:

```
        app = DjangoDash(
            self.name,
            external_scripts=[
                "/static/plotly/plotly-locale-es.js",
            ],
        )
```

- Configure the `Graph` with the locale.

```
    app.layout = [
       dcc.Graph(
            id="my_graph",
            config={"locale": 'es'},
       )
    ]
```